# jquery scroller that wraps onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen carousel and tiny carousel's in other websites but when I use them it seems to clog up the site. I have a scroller that I use already that has arrows to scroll. I just need it to wrap when it reaches the end, and since most of the scrollers I have seen hide the wrap within the jquery, I am unsure of how to do it. This is what I have so far below:

HTML

```
<div id="this">
  <div class="outerwrapper">
    <div class="thisisit"></div>
    <div class="thisisit"></div>
    <div class="thisisit"></div>
    <div class="thisisit"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrows">
    <div class="left" id="left"></div>
    <div class="right" id="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function () {  

$("#right, #left").click(function () {
    var dir = this.id == "right" ? '+=' : '-=';
    $(".outerwrapper").stop(false,true).animate({ scrollLeft: dir + '251' }, 1000);
  });

});
```

The scroller works fine going left to right and back, but I want it to be wrapped around at the end. I use jquery 1.7.1 min.js.

Comment: your question is not clear .

Comment: I need to have the scroller wrap to the first image when clicking right, same for clicking left to the last image